# how to set timeout for connection in jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I am trying jhipster with uaa architect and want to set a timeout for the connection. For example, after login, if a user is not active for 15 mins  and then try to make some option again, I hope the page will require a re-login.
How should achieve this? I tried to read some docs but not find the latest config guides...

I tried following:

1. > ```
   > server:
   >    port: 8080
   >    address: localhost
   >    sessionTimeout: 15000
   > ```
2. > ```
   > security:
   >     authentication:
   >         oauth:
   >             token-validity-in-seconds: 900
   > ```
3. > ```
   > zuul:
   >     host:
   >         connect-timeout-millis: 5000
   >         socket-timeout-millis: 15000
   >
   > hystrix:
   >     command:
   >         default:
   >             execution:
   >                 isolation:
   >                     thread:
   >                         timeoutInMilliseconds: 15000
   > ```

Comment: Hi, I have tried it on application.yml files, locate on both uaa server and gateway. After change the file, I just stop the server, and run ./mvnw again. Should do something else?

Comment: It's correct, I'm not uaa expert but I guess your setting may apply to access tokens and not to refresh tokens. Sorry, I can't help.